# How do I turn off screen turnoff during call?

Tags: calls, android-10, proximity-sensor, realme

Even though thr light sensor still works as Ive checked, it turns of screen automatically no matter how lighted the area is and i can only reuse the screen once the call is over. I've followed other directions to check call settings, but i couldn’t find any settings to modify that there. Is there any other ways to disable this?

To reiterate, I'm running Android 10 on Realme 7i.

Comment: If you speak about "light sensor" do you mean the proximity sensor or the brightness sensor? The latter just measures the environment light, the first emits a short light signal and checks if it is reflected by something next to the screen/sensor.

Answer (score 0):

The screen off feature in phone apps use the proximity sensor rather than the luminosity sensor. I am saying this because my device doesn't have a luminosity sensor, but the screen turns off as soon as I bring it near my face during a call.

To answer your question: There is no Android system setting for this as far as I know. It is completely up to the phone app whether it will turn off the screen. If the caller app that you are using does not give you an option to keep the screen on, your only option is to try other apps that have this feature.